# If a scalar is added to a Dirichlet process with a normal base distribution, is the resulting process also Dirichlet?

Tags: dirichlet-process

Let $\theta_i | G \sim G$ and $G|\alpha \sim DP(\alpha, G_0)$ with $G_0 \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. For a scalar k, does $\theta_i + k | G' \sim G'$ with $G'|\alpha \sim DP(\alpha, G'_0)$ and $G'_0 \sim N(k,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: I think in your (and also standard) notation "$\sim G$" means "is distributed according to $G$" (or in a generative hierarchical way it can be seen as "it is sampled from the distribution $G$''). If so and the Dirichlet process as a normal base measure as stated in the question (and not a random scalar normally distributed i.e., $G_0 \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$) if think the notation should be $G_0 = N(0,\sigma^2)$ (i.e., $G_0$ is the Gaussian distribution and not a random realization from the Gaussian distribution). The same applies to $G'_0$. The answer is yes as @Xi'an has already commented